Exchange Server / Auto-Response
I have an Exchange Server with shared mailboxes where every incoming email should be answered with a message. However, I am not referring to the one-time message from the Out of Office assistant. Is something like this possible on Exchange Server 2016 without using any additional software?
Does anyone have any tips for me? Thanks!

Yes, you can set up automatic replies for shared mailboxes in Exchange Server 2016 without using additional software.

Using the Exchange Management Shell (PowerShell)
You can use the Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration cmdlet to configure automatic replies for a shared mailbox. Here is a basic example:

Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity "SharedMailbox" -AutoReplyState Enabled -InternalMessage "Your internal auto-reply message" -ExternalMessage "Your external auto-reply message"
Replace "SharedMailbox" with the actual name of your shared mailbox and customize the internal and external messages as needed.

Using the Exchange Admin Center (EAC)


Sign in to the Exchange Admin Center.
Navigate to Recipients > Shared.
Select the shared mailbox you want to configure.
Click Edit (pencil icon).
Go to Mailbox Features.
Scroll down to Automatic Replies and click View Details.
Enable automatic replies and set the internal and external messages.


Thanks. I use Exchange Server 2016 and there is no possibility to make changes in Automatic Replies, because this option doesn't exists.

Oops! The auto-reply feature may not be available due to some configuration or limitations in the Exchange Server 2016 settings. Here are some alternatives you can try:

If you have administrative privileges, you can use PowerShell to create a transport rule for auto-replies:
New-TransportRule -Name "AutoReplyRule" -SentTo "sharedmailbox@domain.com" -ApplyHtmlDisclaimerLocation "Append" -ApplyHtmlDisclaimerText "Your auto-reply message here" -FallbackAction Wrap


Replace "sharedmailbox@domain.com" with your shared mailbox address and customize the auto-reply message.

Sometimes, problems with auto-replies can be related to the Autodiscover configuration. Make sure that Autodiscover is set up correctly and running properly. You can test this by running the Test Email AutoConfiguration tool in Outlook:


Hold down the CTRL key and right-click the Outlook icon in the system tray.
Select Test Email AutoConfiguration.
Enter your email address and password, and then click Test.


Thanks for your help.
I tried it. I created the new TransportRule but i don't get Autoreplay. It looks like the switch "FallbackAction Wrap" doesnt exists.
The Rule ist active on the exchange server with the right email from the mailbox, but nothing happened.
Any other tips for me?

If the Transfer Rules method doesn't work, you can set up inbox rules for shared mailboxes directly in Outlook:

Open Outlook and go to File > Manage Rules and Alerts.
Click New Rule.
Select Apply rules to my incoming mail and click Next.
Select the desired conditions (for example, for all messages or specific conditions).
Select Reply using a specific template.
Click the specific template and create an auto-reply message.
Click Finish to complete the rule setup.

Make sure that the shared mailbox has the necessary permissions and that there are no conflicting rules or settings that might prevent the auto-reply from working.
